# onclick not firing on td when outside element has focus

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a `<input>` which performs a search in Javascript when onchange, onkeydown etc fires. This builds a `<table>` of results which is displayed below the `<input>` using `position: absolute`. This works.

The table contains clickable cells

```
let td = document.createElement ("td");
tr.appendChild (td);
td.appendChild (document.createTextNode (search_result.label));
td.onclick = create_click_handler (search_result);
```

The issue is that if the `<input>` has focus then `onclick` only fires on the *second* click. So if I perform this sequence of actions:

- type search text (results are built)
- click a `<td>` (nothing happens)
- click the `<input>` to regain focus (nothing happens)
- click a `<td>` (nothing happens)
- click the `<input>` to regain focus (nothing happens)
- click a `<td>` (nothing happens)
- click the `<input>` to regain focus (nothing happens)
- click a `<td>` (nothing happens)
- click a `<td>` (NOW the onclick handler is called!)

When `td.onclick` fires, it runs correctly. If I trap "Event Listener Breakpoints" for `Mouse > click` in Firefox's Debugger, this confirms that `onclick` does not happen at all for the first click. In other words, this seems to be because of something in the DOM rather than something wrong with the Javascript.

The behaviour is the same in Firefox and Chrome, so I assume it's "correct" behaviour according to some standard.

How can I ensure the first click on this td always triggers the event handler?

Comment: you'd have to post some more code, your description sounds like it should be working ok, i ran some test code locally and it works fine

Comment: Can I see you total code,please?